# How to fix the problem to build docker image for the substrate-node-template

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker

I try to build a docker image for the https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template.

I used this file to do it. `Dockerfile.dev`.

```
FROM paritytech/ci-linux:production as build

WORKDIR /code
COPY . .
RUN cargo build --release

FROM ubuntu:22.04
WORKDIR /node

# Copy the node binary.
COPY --from=build /code/target/release/node-template .

# Install root certs, see: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9984
# RUN apt update && \
#     apt install -y ca-certificates && \
#     update-ca-certificates && \
#     apt remove ca-certificates -y && \
#     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

EXPOSE 9944
CMD [ "./node-template", "--dev" ]
```

When I run `docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t wolfmorgan/xcavate-substrate-node .`, I got this.

```
9.664 info: downloading component 'rust-analyzer'
11.02 info: downloading component 'rust-src'
11.43 info: downloading component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
15.25 info: downloading component 'rust-std'
21.11 info: downloading component 'rustc'
35.06 info: downloading component 'rustc-dev'
54.36 info: downloading component 'rustfmt'
54.95 info: removing previous version of component 'rust-std' for 'wasm32-unknown-unknown'
59.43 info: rolling back changes
59.44 error: could not rename component file from '/usr/local/rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/wasm32-unknown-unknown/lib' to '/usr/local/rustup/tmp/pz7l5tq2toy2zfqw_dir/bk'
59.45
59.45 Caused by:
59.45     Invalid cross-device link (os error 18)
------
Dockerfile.dev:5
--------------------
   3 |     WORKDIR /code
   4 |     COPY . .
   5 | >>> RUN cargo build --release
   6 |
   7 |     FROM ubuntu:22.04
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cargo build --release" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Please help me to fix this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some researching:

- https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/1239
- https://github.com/paritytech/metadata-portal/issues/535

The issue arises from an incorrect built-in toolchain version. To resolve this, we should prioritize reading the project's `rusttoolchain.toml` file and updating the toolchain accordingly. However, this update may result in an "Invalid cross-device link (os error 18)" error. The solution is to remove the existing built-in toolchain and manually install it ourselves.

Solution:

```
# This is an example build stage for the node template. Here we create the binary in a temporary image.

# This is a base image to build substrate nodes
FROM docker.io/paritytech/ci-linux:production as builder

WORKDIR /node-template
COPY . .
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/rustup /usr/local/cargo && \
    curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y --default-toolchain none && \
    rustup show && \
    cargo build --release

# This is the 2nd stage: a very small image where we copy the binary."
FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04
LABEL description="Multistage Docker image for Substrate Node Template" \
  image.type="builder" \
  image.authors="alan.ma.dapps@gmail.com" \
  image.vendor="Substrate Developer Hub" \
  image.description="Multistage Docker image for Substrate Node Template" \
  image.source="https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template" \
  image.documentation="https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template"

# Copy the node binary.
COPY --from=builder /node-template/target/release/node-template /usr/local/bin

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -U -s /bin/sh -d /node-dev node-dev && \
  mkdir -p /chain-data /node-dev/.local/share && \
  chown -R node-dev:node-dev /chain-data && \
  ln -s /chain-data /node-dev/.local/share/node-template && \
  # unclutter and minimize the attack surface
  rm -rf /usr/bin /usr/sbin && \
  # check if executable works in this container
  /usr/local/bin/node-template --version

USER node-dev

EXPOSE 30333 9933 9944 9615
VOLUME ["/chain-data"]

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/node-template"]
```

Comment: Which image source should I use? @AurevoirXavier?

Comment: It is totally up to you. I use `ubuntu:latest`.

Comment: I used `ubuntu:latest`, but got the same error.

Comment: What's your docker file content?

Comment: It is not easy to paste here, if you let me know your email or other communication tool, i will contact via it.

Comment: Ah, I already shared it when I post this question. Just I replaced `22.04` -> `latest` under your suggestion.

Comment: Could you share your repo? I'd love to test it.

Comment: Sure, here it is.
https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you. @AurevoirXavier. It worked for me well.

Comment: By the way, I want to get ws://127.0.0.1:9944. But I am getting only `Running JSON-RPC server: addr=0.0.0.0:9944`. I want to get `Running JSON-RPC WS server: addr=127.0.0.1:9944, allowed origins=["*"]`. Is it possible? @AurevoirXavier